Can a layer style be read-only or locked to a GeoPackage?
Can I "lock" a style to a layer in a GeoPackage file? In a QGIS project I can set a layer to be read-only from the Project Properties -> Data Sources. This makes the layer read-only. But is there something equivalent for a style to be read-only?
The scenario is that I have a layer with a style I've made and the layer and the style is saved to a GeoPackage. Then I want to send this file to someone else, but I would like to prevent (at least to some extent) the next person from editing the style.

When looked from the GeoPackage side, a GeoPackage file (actually an SQLite database) is a single file and it is not possible to set individual tables, in this case a "layer_styles" table, into read-only. It is possible to set the whole .gpkg file into read-only from the file system. In this case the user may need to open the .gpkg file as "immutable" as documented in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html#dataset-open-options. However, if your user downloads the .gpkg file from the net you cannot force them to set the file as read-only. You could burn the file on a non-writable CD/DVD disk and send that to your user but it does not feel reasonable nowadays. And the first thing your user would do is to copy the file away from the CD once they have managed to find a computer with a working CD reader.
The best option might be to have a new option in QGIS for setting the layer styles into read-only from the project settings. This is propably not a common need but you can make a feature request in GitHub https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new/choose.
You could help your users with getting back the original styles by saving a backup copy of the LAYER_STYLES table into the GeoPackage database.
CREATE TABLE layer_styles_backup AS SELECT * FROM layer_styles
